# How do I find acceleration at $x=4$?

Tags: calculus

The question is a three part question. Part a) asked to find the average velocity with the equation $y= -\frac{1}{25}x^2 + \frac{4}{5}x$ on the interval $[6,10]$. Part b) asked to find the instantaneous velocity at $x=6$ and $x=10$. Part c) asks to find the acceleration at $x=4$. So I am not sure what to do after part b).

Comment: Isn't this question not well posed? The interval of definition is [6,10] and
the request is to find the acceleration at $x=4$.

Comment: It says to find the average velocity on that interval --- it doesn't say the function is defined only on that interval.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $y$ is meant to stand for a distance, and $x$ is meant to stand for time, then, as you probably know, instantaneous velocity is the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$. Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity with respect to $x$. So if you know what to do to $y$ to get the velocity, then you know what to do to the velocity to get the acceleration.

Comment: Hi Gerry, quick question: is there really a difference between *a rate* and *a rate of change*? After a thinking about this I noticed some authors define a rate in the following way: *a rate is the ratio between two related quantities in different units*; I'm wondering if *a rate of change* could be defined in this way too. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Taylor, a comment on a ten year old answer is not the place to raise a new question. Better to post it as a new question, where everyone can weigh in on it.

Comment: Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is the instantaneous rate of change of position.  Assuming $y(t)$ is position-time, we have

$$V(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{2}{25}x+\frac{4}{5}$$

and acceleration is the instantaneous rate of change of velocity:

$$A(x) = \frac{dV}{dx} = -\frac{2}{25}$$

Simply find now $A(4)$.